# Improper integral using complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis

Compute 
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ax}}{1+x^2}\,\,dx,\;\; a>0$$ 
using complex analysis.

I tried to integrate the fucntion $f(z)=\frac{e^{-az}}{1+z^2}$ over the contour 
$\gamma$ with counter-clockwise orientation: 
[image: Enter Description Here]

but with no luck.

**Edit** The answers are great but lets keep this question open until someone maybe finds a way to solve this integral using complex analysis.

Comment: I think that this integral has no closed form.

Comment: I myself am not really advanced in complex analysis, but I would suggest a real analysis approach in which you label your integral $f(a)$ and differentiate under the integral sign twice, obtaining $f''(a)$. Upon adding together $f(a)$ and $f''(a)$ you'll yield a solvable integral. From there it is a matter of solving a differential equation.

Comment: Try a rectangle with sides parallel to the axes. on the sides where the real part of $z$ is constant the integral is simple. where the imaginary part is constant you'll get something similar to the starting integral. Olny need to be careful and avoid the poles

Answer (score 3):

As I already mentioned in the comments, I did not achieve the result through complex-analysis.

Instead I used the following real-analysis approach.

Let
$$f(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ax}}{1+x^2}\,\,dx,\;\; a>0.$$
Then,
$$f''(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2\cdot e^{-a\cdot x}}{1+x^2}\ dx.$$
It follows that
$$f''(a)+f(a)=\int_0^{\infty}\ e^{-a\cdot x}\ dx.$$
Evaluate the integral:
$$f''(a)+f(a)=\frac{1}{a}.$$
A general solution to this differential equation can be defined as the sum of a complementary solution and particular solution.

Find the complementary solution by solving the equation:
$$f''(a)+f(a)=0.$$
It can be derived that the complementary solution is given by
$$f_\text{c}(a)=C_{1}\cdot\cos(a)+C_{2}\cdot\sin(a).$$

Find the particular solution to
$$f''(a)+f(a)=\frac{1}{a}$$
by variation of parameters.

List the basis solutions in $f_{\text{c}}(a)$:
$$f_{b,1}(a)=\cos(a),\\ f_{b,2}(a)=\sin(a).$$
Determine the Wronskian of $f_{b,1}(a)$ and $f_{b,2}(a)$:

$$W(a)=
    \begin{vmatrix}
    \cos(a) & \sin(x) \\
    \frac{d}{da}\cos(a) & \frac{d}{da}\sin(a) \\
    \end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
    \cos(a) & \sin(x) \\
    -\sin(a) & \cos(a) \\
    \end{vmatrix}
=\cos^2(a)+\sin^2(a)=1.$$
Let
$$g(a)=\frac{1}{a},\\ h_{1}(a)=-\int \frac{g(a)\cdot f_{b,2}(a)}{W(a)}\ da,\\ h_{2}(a)=\int \frac{g(a)\cdot f_{b,1}(a)}{W(a)}\ da.$$
The particular solution will be given by
$$f_{\text{p}}(a)=h_{1}(a)\cdot f_{b,1}(a)+h_{2}(a)\cdot f_{b,2}(a).$$
Determine $h_{1}(a)$ and $h_{2}(a)$:
$$h_{1}(a)=-\int \frac{\sin(a)}{a}\ da=-\text{Si}(a),\\ h_{2}(a)=\int \frac{\cos(a)}{a}\ da=\text{Ci}(a).$$
The particular equation is given by
$$f_{\text{p}}(a)=\text{Ci}(a)\cdot\sin(a)-\text{Si}(a)\cdot \cos(a).$$
A general solution is defined as the sum of the complementary solution and particular solution:
$$f(a)=C_{1}\cdot\cos(a)+C_{2}\cdot\sin(a)+\text{Ci}(a)\cdot\sin(a)-\text{Si}(a)\cdot \cos(a).$$
From the above expression for $f(a)$ can be derived that $\lim \limits_{a \to \ 0} f(a)=C_{1}$. From the integral form of $f(a)$ can be derived that $\lim \limits_{a \to \ 0} f(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Therefore, $C_{1}=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

From the above expression for $f(a)$ can be derived that $\lim \limits_{a \to \ \infty} f(a)=C_{2}\cdot \sin(\infty)$. From the integral form of $f(a)$ can be derived that $\lim \limits_{a \to \ \infty} f(a)=0$. Therefore, $C_{2}=0$.

Thus, an expression in closed form for your integral is given by
$$f(a)=\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot\cos(a)+\text{Ci}(a)\cdot\sin(a)-\text{Si}(a)\cdot \cos(a),\;\; a>0.$$

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you evaluate numerically this integral, but if you are happy with a special function take the exponential integral defined by
$$
E_1(z)=\int_z^{\infty}\frac{e^{-z}}{z}dz  \space\ \space\ \space\ \left| Arg(z)\right|<\pi
$$
Then complexifying
\begin{align*}
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-az}}{(z-i)(z+i)}dz &=-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{i}{2}\frac{e^{-az}}{z-i}dz+ \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{i}{2}\frac{e^{-az}}{z+i}dz=-\int_{-ia}^{\infty}\frac{ia}{2}\frac{e^{-a(z+i)}}{az}dz + \\ &+\int_{ia}^{\infty}\frac{ia}{2}\frac{e^{-a(z-i)}}{az}dz= \frac{ia}{2} \left( -e^{-ia}E_1(-ia) + e^{ia}E_1(ia) \right)
\end{align*}